# I'm trying to add a toolbar dynamically but not sure how to get access to the view controller to add tool bar view

Tags: ios, ios5, uitoolbar

I'm new to this...

I have a view controller based on a UITableView 
.h file

```
@interface OAFeaturesViewController : UITableViewController<PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>
```

I can create / add the toolbar but it winds up attached to the tableView when i use

[self.view addSubview:myToolBar];

How do I get a reference to the main window so I can add it to the bottom of the main screen where it belongs?
.m file

```
UIToolbar *myToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
myToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,430, 44);
UIBarButtonItem *takePicButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Take Pic" style:(UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered) target:self action:@selector(takePictureWithCamera)];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelPicButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:(UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered) target:self action:@selector(cancelPictureWithCamera)];


NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: takePicButton, cancelPicButton, nil];
[myToolBar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

[self.view addSubview:myToolBar];

```
UIImage *toolbarBkg = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"Navbar_background_solidblue.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];

if ([myToolBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:)])
{
    [myToolBar setBackgroundImage:toolbarBkg forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    NSLog(@"toolbar responds to selector");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"toolbar does NOT respond to selector");
    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:toolbarBkg];
    background.frame = myToolBar.frame;
    [myToolBar insertSubview:background atIndex:0];

}


[self.view  bringSubviewToFront:myToolBar];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *UINavigationController* and activate the toolbar:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=NO;
```

Then, if you want to add items to your toolbar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, flexibleItem, item2, nil];   
self.toolbarItems = items;

[flexibleItem release];
[item1 release];
[item2 release];
```

*flexibleItem* is created in order to maintain a gap between the two items created.

Comment: [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubView:myToolBar]; Solved the background and placement however the buttons are not showing up. I think I can figure that out. Thank you for your help.